# Flick or Toss ball

Tags: android, flicker

I'm currenty creating a project that allow user to drag the ball and flick the ball towards
the goal (football penalty kick/basketball shooting game).I've been searching on how
to flick the ball that will create a trajectory or even thrown into direction which
intended by the user.

I modified the project uploaded in below path but there is no success.I was able to stop the constant moving of the robot, which dragging of the image in any parts of the screen was left but I was not able to create another changes.

http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/

I'm needing an example similar to kicking the ball or flicking the ball or tossing the paper game.

Thank you.